# Problem merging multiple paths of KML files (saved as SHP) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, kml, merge, google-earth

I have several KML files (trail01.kml, trail02.kml etc.) each containing multiple paths (about 30) created in Google Earth. I have opened them in QGIS and saved them as SHP (trail01.shp, trail02.shp etc.), merged the paths so that each SHP contains one path (one feature, as in one line in attribute table instead of 30), and then saved them as KML files and opened them in Google Earth again.

The problem is that when I try to show the elevation profile of a (now) single path, the topology isn't right, as if the previous 30 paths weren't merged in the right order (the profile travels from the beginning of one path to the end of it, and then jumps to another start point, which isn't the next path but seemingly a random one).

I've sorted the paths in Google Earth so that they are in right order in the KML file (if that makes a difference?), and they show up in the right order in the attribute table in the SHP file. I've also tried multistage merging, meaning merging only two paths at a time, but the same problem occurs.

I have very basic skills in Python which I'm willing to try, I just don't have a good idea where to start?

Comment: What did you use for merging? Dissolve?

Comment: I selected the features and used Edit -> Merge Selected Features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these, maybe one solve it:

Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Singleparts to multipart

Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Dissolve

Comment: Thank you! Singleparts to multipart -tool worked and solved this problem!